# I was asked to use * to print "DJE". The result is out of order. How can I solve it?

Tags: java

### I try to print result like this

[the result should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCSux.png)

### Here is my code

```
public class PrintInitials{
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("    ******           *************          **********");
    System.out.println("    **    **               **               **");
    System.out.println("    **     **              **               **");
    System.out.println("    **      **             **               **");
    System.out.println("    **      **             **               ********");
    System.out.println("    **      **       **    **               **");
    System.out.println("    **     **         **   **               **");
    System.out.println("    **    **           ** **                **  ");
    System.out.println("    ******              ****                **********");
    System.out.println("");


}
```

### I tried to move some *s position, but it did`t work

[I got result like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EbXq.png)

Comment: Change all the tabs to spaces and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your code does not have any tabs in it. If you want consistent spacing you have to use the space character.

Comment: Thank you. l got it. l wonder what is the difference between TAB and spaces. Why did

Comment: Why TAB did not wwork?

Comment: @KMING tab depends on  what the tab-stop is set to. The tab-stop is the number of spaces to put out for each tab. So if the tab stop is set to 5 then it looks like a single space in the source code but when it prints out each tab becomes 5-spaces.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you currently have a mix of tabs and spaces; for consistent output use spaces - tabs are not always the same width. Another option, encode your message in binary and then display it. For example,

```
long[] arr = { 1108316309685247L, 857619170329344L, 851022100562688L, 
        847723565679360L, 847723565679612L, 847730008130304L,
        851025321788160L, 857620881605376L, 1108308727432191L };
for (long v : arr) {
    System.out.print("    ");
    for (char ch : Long.toBinaryString(v).toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(ch == '1' ? '*' : ' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

which will guarantee that spaces are spaces. As for how we arrive at that, simply use `Long.parseLong(String, 2)` on

```
11111100000000000111111111111100000000001111111111
11000011000000000000000110000000000000001100000000
11000001100000000000000110000000000000001100000000
11000000110000000000000110000000000000001100000000
11000000110000000000000110000000000000001111111100
11000000110000000110000110000000000000001100000000
11000001100000000011000110000000000000001100000000
11000011000000000001101100000000000000001100000000
11111100000000000000111100000000000000001111111111
```

Comment: l understand that tabs and spaces are different. Thank you for teaching me. Have a good day.